# C# DragDrop; How to retrieve the source's parent?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I have a WinForm with 3 different groupboxes. Furthermore my WinForm contains a tablelayoutpanel with another panel in each cell that can contain objects.

When dragging these objects into a groupbox I should trigger an action based on the cell of the tablelayout the object came from.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to determine the parent panel of the dragged object.

How can I best do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below to access a cell in particular the cell panel. And then save this panel instance to a public variable and acsess while you perform drag over,drag enter or wherever you need it.

```
var currentlySelected = layoutPanel.Cell(x,y).Controls[0] as Panel
```

Comment: Ok, this could work, but forgive me for not understanding completely. The tablelayout's cells each contain a panel, and the panels can contain multiple objects. How do I know, when selecting a random object, in what panel that object is currently kept?

Comment: As you said, panel is the default parent ( since cell has a panel and all control placed inside cell is essentially go inside the panel). And the above code give you the panel object when you click on any control within cell. Now stored the currently selected panel to a public variable (above example saves it in private currentlySelected). You will now have panel reference (public variable) which is the parent of currently selected object/control. I hope it is clear.